Other than for obvious spam, what is OP_RETURN used for in non-coinbase transactions?
Some time a go I heard from Bitcoin Mechanic that there was a coin join implementation that inscribes some data that they need in order to determine their pricing.
Is that true? Do custodians such as Liquid use OP_RETURN for anything?
Other than for many forms of spam, what is OP_RETURN used for in non-coinbase transactions?
Or in other words, lets say that starting from tomorrow there is no OP_RETURN other than that used in coinbase transactions, what would be broken in such scenario?

Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105881/5406

The main use of op_return outputs is that junk gets written to op_return outputs instead of output scripts that are part of the UTXO set.
